# failed binder transaction in restoring contacts in android with phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am getting failed binder trascation error while restoring contacts in android with phonegap. I google it and i come to know that its problem of buffer size. Can we extend buffer? If not than do we have any other solution for this apart from dividing data???? Here in my code is work if length of the array is near about 400 but if i incrsed lenth to 800 then its gives me error.

Below is my code..

```
for(var kl=0;kl<json2.length;kl++){
        var myContact = navigator.contacts.create(JSON.parse(json2[kl]));
        myContact.save(onSuccess,onError);
}
```

Thanks
Yogesh Patel